# Does iText provide mechanism for overlapping margins?

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, margins

I've been trying to organize sections with multiple margins, but they ofter overlap with other margins:

- HEADER / SECTION / CONTENT
- HEADER / CONTENT / SECTION
- CONTENT / SECTION / CONTENT
- SECTION / SUBSECTION

Each of those has different set of margins; HEADER has to have margins, no matter if it's followed by CONTENT or SECTION and SECTION should also have some margins to separate it from CONTENT.

This results with case where HEADER's margin and SECTION's margins are overlapping, creating double-sized margin.

**Is there any margin mechanism in iText that can result with taking Max(margin1,margin2) instead of Sum(margin1,margin2)?**

Comment: Which iText version are you using?

Comment: ~2.1.7, older one

It seems, that using spacingBefore() on Section along with Header margins worked.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion for iText 2/5. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HEADER margin/padding bottom (I don't remember which one we've been always using until now) along with 'spacingBefore' for Section Paragraphs worked just fine.